# SQL Query into Hibernate takes infinite time

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to execute an SQL query into Hibernate because of the complexity of it. To do so, I am using the following method:

```
session.createSQLQuery(sSql).list();
```

And the SQL query is:

```
String sSql = "select timestamp, value, space_name, dp_id, dp_description from "+sTable+
            " inner join space_datapoint on id = dp_id and timestamp between "+
            " (select max(timestamp)-30 day from "+sTable+") and (select max(timestamp) day from "+sTable+")"+
            " order by space_name";
```

The SQL query tries to retrieve a set of values by means of cross references between multiple table/views. The result is a list of objects (different fields from the tables). I have tested the query in the SQL manager of the database and it works. However, when I run it inside the Hibernate framework, it takes a lot of time (I had to stopped the debugger after some minutes, whereas it should take over 5 seconds according to the tests). Do you know what could be the mistake? Or a possible solution?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Could you provide the sql code ?
Also, if you run it into a debugger and you pause the execution, where does it stops ? 
You can also use JVisualVM and it's Sampler to figure where the thread is looping

Comment: Now, it is edited with the SQL query. Regarding the debug, it just stops in the createSQLQuery line and keeps "stepping" without answer for a while

Comment: Regarding the Debug, I was thinking of using using `pause` on the debugger to see the current stacktrace. You should see it hanging in one hibernate function

Comment: It could also be because of a lock in your database (probably by your SQL manager session, since this one does not block). Try killing the SQL Manager then retry

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. However, event releasing the manager and chacking some other features of the session factory, the result is the same.

Comment: sorry, no other ideas. Tell me when you found the issue (to satisfy my curiosity :) )

Comment: How many objects are you expecting it to return?

Comment: Is your transaction isolation level the same via hibernate and via SQL manager?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! First of all, it is approximately 2 million rows which take some time, but not even 1 hour as I left the test mode running. And regarding the isolation level, it is the same.

Comment: 2 million rows is still a lot to load for Hibernate (it will create a HashMap for each if I remember well). What's your heap status (monitor with JVisualVM) ? You should also try limiting your query to only a few lines.

Also, SQL Manager will often read only the first 50 or so lines. That can make a huge difference compared to the 2M Hibernate will load